# "default" font they use for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't actually mean the default font they use on the editor, but the font that appear in the images on the site itself.

For example this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFWiP.jpg
https://code.visualstudio.com/images/1_14_js-refactoring.gif

It's not Consolas or Menlo because of how it renders the "g". I'm just trying to get that exact same look on Windows, but I can't find a good match.

Comment: This is not the correct forum for asking about which font is used in an image, as it is explicitly not about programming.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts

Comment: @hans-passant Cannot be Deja Vu because the "0" is displayed differently. It also doesn't quite look the same.

Answer (score 14):

It is virtually impossible to know which font they are using unless they explicitly say. I do not know of any place where they do.

Within the stock version of VS Code, unless you specify otherwise in `settings.json`, the default font priority is: `Consolas`, `Courier New`, and then `monospace`.

According to the *Default Settings* pane of `settings.json`:

```
// Controls the font family.
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
```